# Pipeline keeps failing at test and lint stage

Tags: numpy, pip, gitlab, pytest, requirements.txt

I am pretty new to coding so I am sorry if I'm not giving enough context. I am trying to package and deploy a model in Python to a repo but keep getting the follow error when I push to GitLab

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.23.1
$ if [[ "${COVERAGE_ARGS}" == "" ]]; then
$ dir_loc=`pwd`
$ COVERAGE_ARGS="--cov=${dir_loc}"
$ fi
$ pytest --junitxml=reports/report.xml --cov-config=${COV_CONFIG} ${COVERAGE_ARGS} ${EXTRA_ARGS}
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.10, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /builds/Ahs1yUQY/1/dse/dscp/dse-dscp-python-hoffinator
plugins: cov-3.0.0, requests-mock-1.9.3
collected 0 items / 1 error
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________ ERROR collecting test/test_main.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module '/builds/Ahs1yUQY/1/dse/dscp/dse-dscp-python-hoffinator/test/test_main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test/test_main.py:5: in <module>
    from src.hoffinator import hoffinator_functions
src/hoffinator/hoffinator_functions.py:3: in <module>
    import numpy as np
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
- generated xml file: /builds/Ahs1yUQY/1/dse/dscp/dse-dscp-python-hoffinator/reports/report.xml -
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.7.10-final-0 -----------
```

My requirements.txt for dependencies is as follows

```
ccplatlogging
boto3~=1.20.33
email-validator~=1.1.3
appnope==0.1.3
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
asttokens==2.0.5
attrs==21.4.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
bleach==5.0.1
cffi==1.15.1
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.2
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
entrypoints==0.4
executing==0.8.3
fastjsonschema==2.16.1
fonttools==4.34.4
iniconfig==1.1.1
ipykernel==6.15.1
ipython==7.34.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.7.1
jedi==0.18.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.1.0
jsonschema==4.7.2
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==7.3.4
jupyter-console==6.4.4
jupyter-core==4.11.1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.1.1
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib==3.5.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
nbclient==0.6.6
nbconvert==6.5.0
nbformat==5.4.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.5
notebook==6.4.12
numpy==1.23.1
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.3
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
patsy==0.5.2
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.2.0
pluggy==1.0.0
ppscore==1.2.0
prometheus-client==0.14.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.30
psutil==5.9.1
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pure-eval==0.2.2
py==1.11.0
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodome==3.15.0
Pygments==2.12.0
pyodbc==4.0.34
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.18.1
pytest==7.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
pyzmq==23.2.0
qtconsole==5.3.1
QtPy==2.1.0
scikit-learn==0.24.2
scipy==1.8.1
seaborn==0.11.2
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
stack-data==0.3.0
statsmodels==0.13.2
teradatasql==17.20.0.0
terminado==0.15.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tinycss2==1.1.1
tomli==2.0.1
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.3.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
widgetsnbextension==3.6.1
```

I do not understand why numpy is not found when it is cleary in the .txt. Is it a version issue?

Comment: It would be wise to share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, too. The script should be stopping when numpy fails to install, rather than forging ahead and blowing up for a more confusing reason.

Comment: Wish I could, but unfortunately, I cannot due to some company pointers..

Answer (score 0):

Your console output shows that you are using Python 3.7.10. If you take a look at `numpy` release notes for 1.23.1 found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.23.1) you’ll notice that it states:

> The Python version supported for this release are 3.8-3.10.

You will need to either use a newer version of Python or use an older version of `numpy`.

Comment: Interesting, when I check my local environment it does say I am on version 3.10.